# Hadoop security using same principal over all nodes

Tags: security, hadoop, kerberos

I have implementing hadoop security using kerberos in windows. I have read [this](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SecureMode.html#Kerberos_principals_for_Hadoop_Daemons_and_Users) document that each nodes should have different principal names. For example, namenode principal like nn/full.qualified.domain.name@REALM.TLD, datanode principal like dn/full.qualified.domain.name@REALM.TLD

My question is why can't we use the same principal for all nodes, I have tested and it also working fine. Then why should we use different principals for each node. Is there any specific reason for that? If we use different principal then the cluster will be more secure? or is there any user role for each service such as hdfs, yarn, mapred?

I just want to know why they are using like that way.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact reason; But the necessity for individual users can be viable for the below scenario;

While each service gets started, some services may require additional privilege to do some operation when ACL is enabled;

- For example: JobHistoryServer should have privilege to write logs about NameNode service communication/status;

Also to the core, Hadoop itself has **"hdfs", "mapred"** as individual users; So its better to have individual users for services;